# Why was Dawn Bellwether (sheep) depicted so small compared to other animals?

Tags: character, zootopia

In Zootopia, why was Dawn Bellwether (sheep) shown so small relative to other animals? In general, all animals preserved distinct proportions based on their kind but not her. She seems of the same size as rabbit Judy:

[image]

Comment: There are outliers in all species...

Comment: Can you imagine a sheep the size of a rabbit?

Comment: Can you imagine a rabbit with a head bigger than a fox's mouth?

Comment: In that particular shot it is the camera perspective. If you look at other occurrences of them standing next to each other the fox will appear significantly larger.

Answer (score 10):

This is done in order to better provide the moral of the film.

The lamb is usually a symbol of innocence and, by size, looks, and behavior, Dawn Bellwether resembles more of a lamb than a sheep. It also triggers some protective instincts.

In the end we get the twist that

> she is actually the mastermind behind it all.

So again the point is made that one should not rely on preconceived ideas.

Answer (score -1):

It is to do with the movie's overall theme of judging others based on race or gender, hence why Bellwether is depicted as what she is.